# what is the issue mobx Error 'Reaction[observerobserved]?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, mobx, mobx-state-tree

Help me pls with this issue:
I'am using mobx-state-tree + React + mobx + Socket.io ,i'm writing chat for project,and using for connection socket.io
From server i get chats list and then put him to mobx-state-tree store using action,then i want get data from mobx-state-tree store and use map function for render elements
But,i catch two errors
This is my mobx-state-tree model for chat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezspr.png)

this is my code where i trying to maping data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzf9u.png)

this is issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJVN3.png)

But error "user" undefined is very stranger,because when i use console.log() for display data,array has this data and displayed in console

Okay,i find problem with Reaction[observerobserved] this happens because component which render chat list was not wrapped into observer function

But i'm still have problem with undefined props of array  when i call map method  on him

Comment: what solution did you find about it ?

Comment: is wrong, because you try get undefined index
in this case 'item.chat_users[index]", solution is use map for chat_users array to, and then render inner item for this data 

"item.chat_users.map(....)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve for |Reaction[observerobserved]"
Need wrapped component into observer()  function for subscribing on changes

For second problem, with undefined prop:

first solution wrong on the screen, because you try get undefined index in this case 'item.chat_users[index]", solution is use map for chat_users array to, and then render inner item for this data "item.chat_users.map(....)"